# From a simplified development perspective, how does HockeyApp work? [not looking for feature list]

Tags: hockeyapp

I'm currently looking into HockeyApp, and would like to know generally what it does from a development perspective and how.  Unfortunately, I've only managed to find what boils down to advertisements listing features without detail of implementations, and the docs.  Neither of these give me a very good idea of what the product actually is.

So my questions are as follows:

1. What ways do users typically interact with the service?
2. What types of non-trivial data manipulation does HockeyApp do?
3. What are the typical interactions involved with setup?
4. What are the typical interactions involved with maintanence?

In any case, I'm going to go ahead and RTFM to figure these things out, and will answer this question if nobody else does.  My logic is that it's best to write my questions before research.  But if someone else wants to answer this, I'd appreciate that as well.

Comment: Disclaimer: I work on HockeyApp and [App Center](https://appcenter.ms)

1: It depends on the type of user. Developers interact with HockeyApp through its web portal, API or CLI

2: Non-exhaustive list:
- Symbolicates your apps' crashes so a human can read them, groups individual crashes
- HockeyApp serves the app binary a developer has uploaded to testers, versions them, tracks install analytics etc.

3: I'm not sure how this deviates from question 1.

4: Do you mean maintenance tasks a developer performs on their app or operations for serving HockeyApp?

Comment: 1. got it -- 2. lot's of hows, what does it alter in the codebase by being in it? -- 3. unavoidable stages? (not instructions) -- 4. after set up, what regular interactions are there?

Comment: 2. HockeyApp does not alter your codebase, our SDK adds functionality to the app to understand and report when your app crashes.
3. Still not sure I understand, I mean, for some of the functionality you want to integrate the SDK, like for crash reporting
4. SDK will be updated, so you might need to follow up on that, upload your versions and symbols to HockeyApp when you release new ones, so it can symbolicate crash reports...